# Can I use TLP for power management (Dell XPS 15 9560)

Tags: nvidia, power

How is power management being done in Elementary at the moment? Power managing the NVidia GPU seems important, and at the moment this is the only article I can find http://www.akitaonrails.com/2017/03/14/enabling-optimus-nvidia-gpu-on-the-dell-xps-15-with-linux-even-on-battery However, it is TLP which is not installed, and so makes me suspect that Elementary might be using a competing power management solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TLP on elementary and it does a lot on my Inspiron machine to save battery.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
```